# how to display the image by calling from two different paths?

Tags: codeigniter

I have an assets folder containing images outside of the root directory. I want the image to be displayed if i using two different paths: for example

```
www.example.com/assets/aa.jpg
www.example.com/assets/test/aa.jpg
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Simple. Put the images in both locations. That's the best suggestion you'll get if you provide this little amount of detail

Comment: For static images that should really be done by the web server or the filesystem.  You can either symlink the directories on disk, or set up aliases in your web server config.  Aliases is probably the better option.

Comment: Either way, that would not be a question related to programming so it would be offtopic here at SO